# VB 6.0 run time error 429, ActiveX object can't create object after Office 2016 installation

Tags: vb6, office365

I am trying to run a application build on VB 6.0 on machine with Office 2016. This application will be using Excel 16 which is throwing runtime error. The exact error is "*Run time error '429': 
ActiveX component can't be created*"
even when i refer the Microsoft Excel 16.0 Object Library. The simple piece of code

```
Set xlapp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
```

is throwing this error.

Operating System: Windows 7 64 Bit; Office version: 2016 32 Bit

Comment: You'd have to post the code.

Comment: when i debug the application, the line "Set en= rdoEnvironments(0)" is throwing this error

Comment: That doesn't really tell us anything, I'm afraid. Also, this isn't technically a VBA question - it's VB6.

Comment: The code does not have any issue really, cause the app works fine on machine with Office v10 or earlier. I see the basic causes for this issue may be a reference missing in VB6, could you please help with any suggestion?

Comment: Fix the reference? Not sure what else you really expect as a suggestion.

Comment: May be if i'd be helped with which references are necessary to VB60 apps when we have Office 2016 to avoid such error? I have tried adding Excel 16 Object library pointing to Excel.exe, but it did not work!

Comment: I have created a new VB60 application which will just export an excel, 
`set myxl = NEW Excel.application`

But still i'm receiving the same error when it runs through above code. I have added "Microsoft Excel 16.0 Object Library"

Comment: Is it 32 or 64bit Office you have installed?

Comment: I have opened the vbp in notepad and found this, Any idea on what is 

`Reference=*\G{*******-****-***-****-*********}#1.0#*#..\..\..\..\..\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office\XL5EN32.OLB#Microsoft Excel 5.0 Object Library`

and what can be equivalent for Office 2016

Comment: The equivalent would be the Excel 16 object library.

Comment: I have added Excel 16 object library, but it is pointing to 

`..Program files(x86)\..\Microsoft\root\Office16\EXCEL.exe` 
Any idea about the missing XL5EN.OLB

Comment: Without the code it's impossible to say why you'd need a reference to Excel5. It's ancient!

Comment: `Private Sub Command1_Click()
    Set xlapp = CreateObject("Excel.Application") 'Since not a sigle instance of Excel, so we create one
    Set xl = New Excel.application
    Set xlwbook = xl.Workbooks.Add
    Set xlsheet = xlwbook.Sheets.Item(1)
    xlsheet.Cells(1, 1) = "Blah blah blah"
    xl.ActiveWorkBook.Save ("c:\myfilename.xls")
End Sub` 


Can this help?

Comment: Nothing there needs Excel5. If you are using old workbooks, have you checked the File Block settings in Excel to ensure they aren't prevented from opening?

Comment: I am using Excel 2016 workbook and trying to create a new workbook of type **.xls**. I have tried changing FileBlock settings for Excel 95, 97, 2007 , But this did not work either.

Comment: The program is throwing this exception at its very first line 
`Set xlapp = CreateObject("Excel.application")`
I have tried the same program on machine with Office 2013 adding reference to **Microsoft Excel 15.0 Object Library**, It is working fine and excels are created.
Does that mean the issue is with **Microsoft Excel 16.0 Object Library** which i'm adding in programs using Office 2016?

Answer (score 2):

Your error is with `rdoEnvironments` which means you are using *Remote Data Objects* and that dependency is missing on the target machine.

RDO was a predecessor of ADO, to rectify the problem you need to try & locate a Remote Data Objects redistributable package from Microsoft, or try to create a [deployment package on the development machine](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/213846) where the required DLLs are present and hope they get picked up.

Rewriting to ADO is worth considering if practical.

Answer (score 0):

I have repaired Microsoft Office 2016 and then added the Microsoft Excel 16.0 Object Library to the VB code. It was able to create the object for excel class and also generated without any flaws :-) Thank you.